# Como pasar parametros a una URL de google earth

Tags: php, java, google-maps, url

tengo una pagina de consulta tipo intranet en html + php en la cual tengo parametros de localizacion tipo UTM, norte este y zona, el cual me gustaria saber como podria pasar estos parametros mediante URL a google earth, tal como se hace con google maps de la siguiente manera: "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=58.698017,-152.522067" y tambien quisiera saber si hay una manera de convertir las coordenadas que tengo en UTM en longitud y latitud pero de manera automatica

Answer (score 0):

esta es la forma que utilizo para pasar la coordenada de la ubicación.
Los valores están en decimal.

Donde:
33.09311337 corresponde a la Latitud
-117.26861887 corresponde a la Longitud

https://earth.google.com/web/@33.09311337,-117.26861887,17.16000156a,285.78132983d,35y,-144.96411702h,77.45370669t,0r